# Using mailcatcher in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I want to use [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) to check if my mails were send. They weren't and i wonder why, because the mailer is generated and definitely called.

So in my config/enviroment/development.rb i wrote:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }
```

my call looks like this:

```
OrderMailer.send_new_order(@order).deliver
```

and finally the generated controller like this:

```
class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  def send_new_order(order)
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: "to@example.org", subject: "Test"
  end
end
```

And mailcatcher runs of course. So why wasn't the mail send?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out, that I used the wrong SMTP Adress for the development env.

It had to be

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "127.0.0.1", :port => 1025 }
```

instead of

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for this? Why localhost didn't work while 127.0.0.1 did.

Comment: @AnonJ I guess it just expected an ip or url, so localhost didn't resolve to anything. Maybe http://localhost would have worked, maybe I'll check this later.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/182

```
$ mailcatcher -f -v
Starting MailCatcher
==> smtp://127.0.0.1:1025
==> http://127.0.0.1:1080
==> SMTP: Received message from '<donotreply@xxx.com>' (676 bytes)
```